# Detect Key not in Key Enum, in Key Event

Tags: c#

We can detect key input by using key event,

```
private void KeyUp_Or_KeyDown_Event(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Key==Key.SomeKey) //detect  key
   {
      //do something           
   }
}
```

but there seems many keys not in the Key Enum (see the link)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.key(v=vs.110).aspx

such as ' \ ' ,  ' [ ' , ' ] ' , ' ` ', ' = ' and so on,

Any Method to detect the key not in the Key Enum ?

Take Textbox for example, 
I want to do it even when user type many random text in textbox, anytime user press the assign key I can detect it.

Comment: Detect those keys in KeyPress instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a quick test application to see the key values for the keys you are looking for.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" KeyDown="Window_KeyDown">
    <TextBlock Name="MyTextBlock">Hit a key</TextBlock>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        MyTextBlock.Text = Enum.GetName(typeof(System.Windows.Input.Key), e.Key);
    }
}
```

Then bang away at the keys to see what the codes are.

Comment: Good job, I find that all keys are in Key Enum, and I think they're not just because I don't know their key name in the enum, thanks!